# Error encountered when building composite chart dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am receiving the following error when trying to build a composite chart in DC.js:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_function () {
>           return dc.utils.subtract(d3.min(getAllXAxisMinFromChildCharts()),
>   _chart.xAxisPadding());
>       }' on string 'xAxisMin'

My composite chart code is as follows:

```
var comChart = dc.compositeChart("#comChart")  
    .width(450)  
    .height(300)
    .elasticX(true)  
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]))  
    .elasticY(true)  
    .brushOn(false)  
    .group(sumGroup)  
    .dimension(dayCountDimension)   
    .compose([  
        dc.lineChart(comChart)  
            .colors('green')  
            .group(group1),  
        dc.lineChart(comChart)  
            .colors('brown')   
            .group(group2)  
        ]);
```

The day count dimension is an int, and all groups are products of a sum map reduce. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you probably have some odd version of the code from between versions. This was fixed [in January 2014](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/504).

Please try updating to the 2.0 betas (preferably - will be released soon), or backing out to 1.7.5.